# Start development server not on the default browser

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I have ASP.NET MVC 4 application and I am debugging it with the built it development server( not IIS) my default browser is firefox so every time I click on "Debug" it open new firefox tab. I want to check my web on chrome also. what is the easiest way to make it? ( I don't want to change my default browser).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose a page in your project and right click and choose browse with and select your browser and set default

[image]

[image]

**In MVC**:

If you right click on `any page other than default.aspx` `you will not get` the "browse with" option.

So, when working on an ASP.NET MVC application, right click on default.aspx and chose "Browse With..." Then you'll get a dialog that will allow you to change your default browser.

**NOTE:**

for ASP.NET MVC3 projecs,You need to specifically add a .htm or .html page, and then right click that and choose Browse With and set to default

**ALternative:**

Default Browser Changer extension
[Link](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/233945ae-0b7b-47e7-9b02-c5a11798afb5)

Comment: @ilayzeidman :for ASP.NET MVC3 projecs,You need to specifically add a .htm or .html page, and then right click that and choose Browse With and set to default.

Comment: I don't have this option can you add a screenshot?

Comment: add a Default.aspx webform in the root of the site and this, when right clicked, will give you the Browse With option

Comment: But in my application I have .cshtml pages and when I right click it I dont have this option

Comment: check my alternative solution

Comment: or just add a .htm page and right clicked on it. There you will have Browse With...

Comment: the defualt browser changer work for me I mark it as solution

Answer (score 1):

When you are in debug mode and it loads in Firefox, copy the url to the other browser.

Then go to Debug > Attach to Process, and select the process for the other browser and click [Attach].

A different approach using powershell scripts [is shown in this blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToChangeTheDefaultBrowserInVisualStudioProgrammaticallyWithPowerShellAndPossiblyPokeYourselfInTheEye.aspx).

Ultimately, the easiest approach would be to use Visual Studio 2012 or 2013, which have this functionality built in to the debug button in the menu.

Comment: I am using visual studio 2010 ultimate where do I have this option?

Comment: @ilayzeidman which option are you referring to? The first one involves debugging the site as normal and then switching the browser to which the debug process is attached.

Comment: sorry, had a typo. VS 2012 and 2013 have it built in. 2010 doesn't. And 2012 and 2013 should both be able to handle 2010 SP1 solutions without introducing any major changes.